# Docker image prune and --filter / --force options

Tags: docker, devops

Using Docker version 19.03.15, build 99e3ed8919 the docker image prune --force and --filter options seem to be not commpliant. Any idea about this issue ?

```
> docker image prune --filter reference="nexus.xxxxx:5000/my_project/*"
WARNING! This will remove all dangling images.
Are you sure you want to continue? [y/N]

> docker image prune --force --filter reference="nexus.xxxxx:5000/my_project/*"
Error response from daemon: Invalid filter 'reference'
```

Comment: According to https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_prune/, `docker image prune` only supports the `until` and `label` filters.

Answer (score 0):

Please, go ahead and check the GitHub documentation below to help you solve this issue:

https://github.com/docker/docker.github.io/issues/10730

Comment: Can you please put the relevant parts of the documentation in your answer?  Link only answers have a tendency to go out of date unfortunately.